# What message causes a button to send a WM_COMMAND message

Tags: c++, button, winapi, wndproc, wm-command

I know that a Button, when clicked, sends the WM_COMMAND message to it's parent, but what message does it receive that makes it send this message? I am overriding the default WndProc of a button and the button does not receive the WM_COMMAND message, so I need to know what message causes a button to send the WM_COMMAND message so I can replicate that functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that it's actually a combination of WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_MOUSELEAVE, and a few other things. For example, the WM_COMMAND will only be fired if the mouse was depressed on the button, and is still on the button when WM_LBUTTONUP is fired. As for space, enter, etc, I believe it just handles the VK_ENTER message and stuff.

Comment: You could call the old WndProc for the button on any messages that you don't explicitly want to trap. (From memory, I think it's `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd,GWL_WNDPROC)` to retrieve it...) That should get your new button sending the `WM_COMMAND` message as normal, whilst letting you hook in to do whatever you're trying to do. Can't really tell whether this is any good for your situation though...

Comment: @brone no it's not, I need to be able to tell whether the button was genuinely "clicked" (according to the rules of a button) apart from the original WndProc, so I can do my own stuff. Trapping WM_COMMAND in the parent window is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall it's WM_LBUTTONUP, but use a Spy program to find out for sure.

Comment: What about when you click on it with the space key? Or the Enter key? Or with an accelerator key?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to override `WM_COMMAND` message because `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message is converted as `WM_COMMAND` message and send it to parent control. This is the mechanism that is done in the background.

You asked about space and enter key.This can be controlled by virtual key codes like `vk_enter` , `vk_tab`...etc.,

Answer (score 0):

WM_COMMAND message is always received by controls parent. If you want to click button programmatically you can do this:

```
::SendMessage( button_handle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0 );
```

LPARAM of WM_COMMAND holds button_handle. So you can extract information about you button calling

```
::GetWindowLongPtr( HWND( lParam ), GWL_USERDATA );
```

You must have been set this information earlier like this

```
::SetWindowLongPtr( button_handle, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>( some_info ) );
```

for example some_info can by pointer to button wrapper object