# Child Window Sends WM_COMMAND Message to Unexpected Parent on Enter Key Press While Focused

Tags: c, windows, winapi

According to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command

[What message causes a button to send a WM_COMMAND message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494278/what-message-causes-a-button-to-send-a-wm-command-message)

(And a lot of other posts)

Window controls send their WM_COMMAND message to their direct parent. But it wasn't the case in this scenario, and I can't figure out why. It only happened with the enter key (Return key).

```cpp
/// Marcos:
#define IDC_BUTTON1 100;
#define IDC_BUTTON2 101;

/// Windows:
HWND g_hWnd;      // Main application window.
HWND g_Container; // Static window (Act like a container)
HWND g_Button1;   // Button 1
HWND g_Button2;   // Button 2
```

1. In the WinMain entry, create the main window, nothing special:

```cpp
g_hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
   CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

2. In the WM_CREATE message:

```cpp
// Button 1 is a direct child of the main window.
g_Button1 = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"Button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 100, 100, 130, 40, g_hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON1, NULL, NULL);
if (!g_Button1)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

// Create the container window(static).
g_Container = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, L"STATIC", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
            300, 300, 500, 500, g_hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
// Subclassing the container window.
if (!g_Container || !SetWindowSubclass(g_Container, WindowProcedure_Container, NULL, NULL))
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

// Button 2 is a direct child of the container window.
g_Button2 = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"Button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 100, 100, 130, 40, g_Container, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON2, NULL, NULL);
if (!g_Button2)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

3. Main window procedure and container window procedure definitions:

```cpp
// Main window procedure:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
       switch (LOWORD(wParam))
       {
       // The main window is the direct parent of button 1, so this message is expected (on click/enter or space key press on focus).
       case IDC_BUTTON1:
       MessageBox(NULL, L"Button 1 clicked", L"Main window", MB_OK);
       return 0;
       // I was not expecting this message to be sent here, but it is, and only when the enter key is pressed.
       // The space key or normal click with the mouse still sends the message to the container window as expected.
       case IDC_BUTTON2:
       MessageBox(NULL, L"Button 2 clicked", L"Main window", MB_OK);
       return 0;
       }
       break;
    }
     // Other unrelated messages handling ...
    default:
       return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
// Container window procedure:
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure_Container(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        // Triggered normally on button click or space key press on focus but not the enter key,
        // The WM_COMMAND message triggered by the enter key is sent to the main window instead of its parent, and I don't know why.
        case IDC_BUTTON2:
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Button 2 clicked", L"Container window", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
     // Remove the window subclass callback.
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
    {
        // Removes installed subclass callback from the window.
        if (!RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &WindowProcedure_Container, uIdSubclass))
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        return 0;
    }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

4. Message loop

```cpp
MSG message = { 0 };
while (GetMessageW(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!IsDialogMessageW(g_hWnd, &message))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessageW(&message);
    }
}
```

I tried search engines and experiments with Spy++.
My first guess was that something blocked the enter key and its message never reached the button, but the Spy++ result says otherwise. It indeed received the key message(KEYDOWN, KEYUP, DLGCODE,..); it just sent the WM_COMMAND message to the main window.

I hit the wall and have no idea what to do next.
I endup try to subclass the button and "suppress" everything and implement my own key handling for the button (it worked)
But I felt like this issue could be solved easier if I knew the root of the problem.

Anyone know what's causing this behavior? Thank you.

EDIT:
Attached single file compile-able code.

Replicate steps: -> Open application -> Use the Tab key to navigate between buttons. Navigate to the second button and press the Enter key. It'll trigger a dialog that shouldn't happen.

Visual Studio 2022: Empty Project
Linker Subsystem: Windows
C++17

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>  // Windows API: Winapi header.
#include <Windowsx.h> // Windows API: Winapi marcos.
#include <Uxtheme.h>  // Windows API: Visual themes and styles.
#include <commctrl.h> // Windows API: Common controls.
#include <string>

// Directive: Enable visual style .
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

// Directive: Include necessary libs:
#pragma comment(lib, "UxTheme.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

// Marcos:
#define IDC_BUTTON1 100
#define IDC_BUTTON2 101

// Global variables:
HINSTANCE g_hInstance; // Global instance.
HWND g_hWnd;           // Main application window.
HWND g_Container;      // Static window (Act like a container)
HWND g_Button1;        // Button 1
HWND g_Button2;        // Button 2

// Forward declarations:
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure_Container(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);

// WinMain Entry:
int WINAPI wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    // Create my custom window class.
    WNDCLASSW my_class = { 0 };
    my_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    my_class.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    my_class.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    my_class.hInstance = hInstance;
    my_class.lpszClassName = L"MyWindowClass";
    my_class.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    g_hInstance = hInstance;

    // Register my window class.
    if (!RegisterClassW(&my_class))
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed to register the window class.", L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    g_hWnd = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"MyWindowClass", L"Window title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        200, 200, 400, 350, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    if (!g_hWnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Failed to create the main window.", L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

    // Enter the message loop.
    MSG message = { 0 };
    while (GetMessageW(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!IsDialogMessageW(g_hWnd, &message))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessageW(&message);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// Procedure definitions:
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        g_Button1 = CreateWindowExW(NULL, WC_BUTTON, L"Button 1", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 5, 5, 130, 40, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON1, NULL, NULL);
        if (!g_Button1)
            return -1;

        // Create the container window(static).
        g_Container = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, WC_STATIC, L"", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_NOPREFIX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
            5, 55, 300, 200, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        // Subclassing the container window.
        if (!g_Container || !SetWindowSubclass(g_Container, WindowProcedure_Container, NULL, NULL))
            return -1;

        // Button 2 is a direct child of the container window.
        g_Button2 = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"BUTTON", L"Button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 5, 5, 130, 40, g_Container, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON2, NULL, NULL);
        if (!g_Button2)
            return -1;

        return 0;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            // The main window is the direct parent of button 1, so this message is expected (on click/enter or space key press on focus).
        case IDC_BUTTON1:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Button 1 clicked (Expected message)", L"Main window", MB_OK);
            return 0;
            // I was not expecting this message to be sent here, but it is, and only when the enter key is pressed.
            // The space key or normal click with the mouse still sends the message to the container window as expected.
        case IDC_BUTTON2:
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Button 2 clicked (Unexpected message, main window is not direct parent of button 2 but it send the message here?)", L"Main window", MB_OK);
            return 0;

        default:
            break;
        }

        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure_Container(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            // Triggered normally on button click or space key press on focus but not the enter key,
            // The WM_COMMAND message triggered by the enter key is sent to the main window instead of its parent, and I don't know why.
        case IDC_BUTTON2:
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Button 2 clicked (Expected message)", L"Container window", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    // Remove the window subclass callback.
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
    {
        // Removes installed subclass callback from the window.
        if (!RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, &WindowProcedure_Container, uIdSubclass))
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        return 0;
    }
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Can we have a [mre] please.  If you put one together you might solve it yourself, anyway.

Comment: Hi, I did try to simplify the code as much as possible, and the above code is the simplest version that reproduces the problem. I'm sorry if it is confusing, it's my first question. Basically, in short, the problem is that I expect button windows to always send their WM_COMMAND message to their direct parent, but it didn't and sent it directly to the main window instead, also only happening with the enter (return) key.

Comment: A lot of us can debug these issues within a few minutes of having a single file example. Something that we can drag and drop into a stock Windows Visual Studio project, compile, and debug. But no one wants to build the solution from code snippets. That's too much to ask.  So please, share a [mcve] if you'd like us to help.

Comment: I see. I will try to make a single file and attach it to the post.

Comment: @0xF5T9 what you have shown is hardly a [mcve], but one problem I see with this code is that `g_hWnd` is being used by `WM_CREATE` before it has been assigned a value. `WM_CREATE` is sent to a new window's `WndProc` while `CreateWindowEx()` is still running. When the main window's `WndProc` is creating its child controls, it needs to use the `HWND` that is passed in to it as a parameter.  `g_hWnd` hasn't been assigned it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, it's my oversight copy-paste mistake. It shouldn't happen in my final code. I have attached a single-file code in the post as requested. Which should be compile-able.

Comment: You should not be writing window procedures and WM_COMMAND handlers in this day and age, or for about the last 20 years. Use MFC (yuck) or ActiveX or one of the other higher-level technologies.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks, but the project I'm working on is strictly restricted to pure WinAPI only.

Comment: It seems unusual to have a STATIC control host child controls. Regardless, I believe `IsDialogMessage` is responsible for transforming navigation keyboard input (such as the Enter key). Does the behavior change if you replace that call from the message loop?

Comment: @IInspectable Omg, you are right. I did some extra searches and found the post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933935/ws-tabstop-in-winapi-on-edit-controls-of-child-windows), which also had your comment on it. Yes. The marked answer points out the problem: I was calling `IsDialogMessage` on the wrong window.

Comment: I change the message loop to `if (!IsDialogMessageW((GetFocus() == g_Container || GetFocus() == g_Button2 ? g_Container : g_hWnd), &message))` and now it sends the message to the correct window. Thank you all.

Comment: By the way, how do I mark the answer properly? I'm new on the platform, and I can't find any mark-answer buttons.

Comment: See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I have reverted your recent edits as they rewrote the question to a solution. Please don't do that.

Comment: @IInspectable "*It seems unusual to have a STATIC control host child controls*" - why? That is literally one of its documented jobs: "*Applications often use static controls to label other controls **or to separate a group of controls**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau *Visually* grouping controls does not imply nor require a child-parent relationship. The standard use case is to have STATIC controls and the enclosed controls be siblings. Indeed, I wouldn't even know how to write a dialog resource where a static control is the parent of other controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling `IsDialogMessageW` on the wrong window. Blindly passing the main window to `IsDialogMessageW` will not achieve the behavior I want and will result in some kind of "message tangling" (I think) that causes unexpected behaviors.

I modified the message loop to catch the key message and make sure it passed the correct window to 'IsDialogMessageW, and now it works fine.

```cpp
MSG message = { 0 };
while (GetMessageW(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (message.message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        switch (message.wParam)
        {
        case VK_TAB:
        {
            if (IsDialogMessageW(g_hWnd, &message))
                continue;

            break;
        }
        case VK_RETURN:
        {
            HWND parent = GetParent(message.hwnd);
            if (IsDialogMessageW((parent == g_hWnd ? g_hWnd : parent), &message))
                continue;

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessageW(&message);
}
```

**Read more:**
[WS_TABSTOP in winapi on edit controls of child windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933935/ws-tabstop-in-winapi-on-edit-controls-of-child-windows) (marked answer)